# parse date from datetime object and then remove duplicates from a list of dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I am pretty new with programming so please ignore any silly mistakes.
I have this list of dictionary which has list of devices connected to a laptop.
In the output I just need unique entries for a day , let say a device A is connected 3times a day in the output list it should only come ones.
so first I have to parse the date from the date time object in below list and just look for duplicates.

help appreciated !

```
devices = [
{'Device Type': 'USB Drive', 'Vendor Id': '05E3', 'Product Id': '0749', 'Serial Number': "'000000001539'", 'Date': '10/19/21 10:32 PM', 'Action': 'Full Access', 'Device': 'CNP150'},
{'Device Type': 'iOS', 'Vendor Id': '05AC', 'Product Id': '12A8', 'Serial Number': "'ABCD'", 'Date': '10/14/21 12:27 AM', 'Action': 'Full Access', 'Device': 'CNP012'},
{'Device Type': 'iOS', 'Vendor Id': '05AC', 'Product Id': '12A8', 'Serial Number': "'ABCD'", 'Date': '10/14/21 5:38 AM', 'Action': 'Full Access', 'Device': 'CNP012'},
{'Device Type': 'iOS', 'Vendor Id': '05AC', 'Product Id': '12A8', 'Serial Number': "'ABCD'", 'Date': '10/14/21 11:59 PM', 'Action': 'Full Access', 'Device': 'CNP012'},
{'Device Type': 'iOS', 'Vendor Id': '05AC', 'Product Id': '12A8', 'Serial Number': "'748123d6d86dd4173371362201a0d8d250145fbf'", 'Date': '10/17/21 6:59 AM', 'Action': 'Full Access', 'Device': 'CNP011'}]
```

output should be -

```
{'Device Type': 'USB Drive', 'Vendor Id': '05E3', 'Product Id': '0749', 'Serial Number': "'000000001539'", 'Date': '10/19/21 10:32 PM', 'Action': 'Full Access', 'Device': 'CNP150'},
{'Device Type': 'iOS', 'Vendor Id': '05AC', 'Product Id': '12A8', 'Serial Number': "'ABCD'", 'Date': '10/14/21 11:59 PM', 'Action': 'Full Access', 'Device': 'CNP012'},
{'Device Type': 'iOS', 'Vendor Id': '05AC', 'Product Id': '12A8', 'Serial Number': "'748123d6d86dd4173371362201a0d8d250145fbf'", 'Date': '10/17/21 6:59 AM', 'Action': 'Full Access', 'Device': 'CNP011'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `groupby` from module `itertools` to group by date. First, create a function that extracts the date from a list entry:

```
def get_date(e):
    return e['Date'].split()[0]
```

Sort the list using that function as the key (`groupby` requires that the sequence to be grouped is sorted) and group it using the same function. Take the first item from each group:

```
from itertools import groupby
[list(group)[0] for _,group in groupby(sorted(devices, key=get_date), 
                                       key=get_date)]
```